# Why does "hello" > 0 return TRUE?

Tags: r

Try it:

```
"hello" > 0
```

I tried using `as.numeric("hello")` but it just gave me back `NA`. What gives?

Comment: This may not return `TRUE` in all locales.  It depends on where the character `"0"` is located in the collation order.

Comment: Characters are ordered "lexically". This also affects how contrasts in regression functions and axis plotting labels get handled by default.

Comment: just out of curiosity, what did you expect?

Comment: `NA` probably. Something that would warn me that I'm trying to compare a string to a number.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because `0` is coerced to `"0"`.  See `help(">")`:

```
 If the two arguments are atomic vectors of different types, one is
 coerced to the type of the other, the (decreasing) order of
 precedence being character, complex, numeric, integer, logical and
 raw.
```