# what's the meaning of "x[] <- as.integer(x)"

Tags: r

When I read R manual, I encountered some lines of code as below(copied from R manual for 'colSums'):

```
x <- cbind(x1 = 3, x2 = c(4:1, 2:5))
dimnames(x)[[1]] <- letters[1:8]
x[] <- as.integer(x)
```

Could someone tell me what the purpose of the last line is? 
Thanks!

Comment: Compare the results of a normal assignment vs. an assignment to `x[]` as so. Compare: `x[] <- as.integer(x); x;` to `x <- as.integer(x); x;`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My understanding is that assigning to `x[]` (or assigning to an object with square brackets, with no values - for those searching for this issue) overwrites the values in `x`, while keeping the `attributes` that `x` may have, including matrix dimensions. In this case, it is helpful to remember that a matrix is pretty much just a vector with dimensions added.

So given...

```
x <- cbind(x1 = 3, x2 = c(4:1, 2:5))
dimnames(x)[[1]] <- letters[1:8]

attributes(x)
#$dim
#[1] 8 2
#
#$dimnames
#$dimnames[[1]]
#[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h"
#
#$dimnames[[2]]
#[1] "x1" "x2"
```

...this will keep the dimensions and names stored as attributes in `x`

```
x[] <- as.integer(x)
```

While this won't...

```
x <- as.integer(x)
```

The same logic applies to vectors too:

```
x <- 1:10
attr(x,"blah") <- "some attribute"

attributes(x)
#$blah
#[1] "some attribute"
```

So this keeps all your lovely attributes:

```
x[] <- 2:11
x
# [1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
#attr(,"blah")
#[1] "some attribute"
```

Whereas this won't:

```
x <- 2:11
x
#[1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
```

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much. You answer is detailed and helpful.

Comment: Though when you have strings, they don't get converted to integers. Why? E.g. x <- cbind(x1 = as.character(3), x2 = as.character(c(4:1, 2:5))); x[] <- is.integer(x)

Comment: @vitor: because converting from character to integer (or logical) may cause information loss.

Comment: @vitor - as per http://stackoverflow.com/a/17030209/496803 , the data type will only be converted if what you are assigning is of a higher precedence - character > complex > numeric > integer > logical > raw.

Answer (score 1):

```
x[] <- as.integer(x)
```

It parses the contents of `matrix x` into integer, then stores it back into x, as a matrix.

```
x[,] <- as.integer(x)
```

also works. But

```
x <- as.integer(x)
```

will lose the matrix structure.