# Given a matrix, x, set all elements below the main diagonal to 0

Tags: r

```
> x<-matrix(seq(1:16),4,4)
> x
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    5    9   13
[2,]    2    6   10   14
[3,]    3    7   11   15
[4,]    4    8   12   16
```

How do I target all elements below the main diagonal and set them to 0, for a generic matrix, not just the example I provided?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do

```
x[lower.tri(x)] <- 0L
```

Another one:

```
x[row(x) > col(x)] <- 0L
```

(`0L`, unlike `0`, is an integer. So using it here will preserve the class of your matrix.)

Comment: Will there be a `class` clash issue here? Wouldn't it be negated by this being a `[<-` call which should retain the attributes, ala http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18501824/whats-the-meaning-of-x-as-integerx ?

Comment: @thelatemail, I don't see any issue, you can give it a test. `x` can be a matrix of `numeric` or `integer`, assigning `0L` will work with both and retain the original class.

Comment: Aha... I think I was getting confused since `class(x) == "matrix"` that you meant you had to use `0L` to stop coercion to a vector. The `type`,`storage.mode`,`mode`,`class` stuff always catches me out.