# R - log() function turns numbers into strings?

Tags: r

This is my R code

```
v2 = 1:10
v3 = c('numeric',length(v2))
for( i in 1:length(v2)) {
    v3[i] = log(v2[i])
}
v3
# [1] "0" "0.693147180559945" "1.09861228866811" etc
```

And, well, it appears the data are strings. Why is that? v2 is a numeric vector.

Comment: It returns Incorrect number of dimensions in v2[, i]

Comment: `log` is vectorised - `v3 <- log(v2)`

Comment: Thanks for the replies, but v3 still contains strings, at least there are quotation marks around the data entries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is in your initialisation of `v3`

```
v3 <- c('numeric',length(v2))
v3
#[1] "numeric" "10"
```

This sets the `class` of `v3` to "character" as you are joining a string of text (literally `"numeric"`) to a numeric value (`length(v2)`, or `10`) - try `class(v3)`. This then also means anything numeric added to the vector will get coerced to a character as well:

```
v3 <- c('numeric',length(v2))
v3[1] <- 1
v3
#[1] "1"  "10"
```

There is a hierarchy of what vectors will be converted to - see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17030209/496803 - character > complex > numeric > integer > logical > raw.

Instead you want:

```
v3 <- numeric(length(v2))
v3
#[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

All of this is of course missing the elephant in the room, which is that `log` will act along an entire numeric vector in one go ("vectorization"):

```
v3 <- log(v2)
v3
# [1] 0.0000000 0.6931472 1.0986123 1.3862944 etc
```

Comment: Thank you!! Wil mark your answer when possible. Why does my code not work though? Sorry I'm relatively new to R.

Comment: @Firkamon - added comment.