# R date format of column based on criteria of other column

Tags: r, date, dataframe, format

Sorry if this is a duplicate, I found many answers where you could change a value in a data frame to a number or string based on another column, however it doesn't seem to work when trying to change each value based on that value.

So  I tried to use some answers for example I read [R - Update a Value in One Column Based on Criteria in Other Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28650957/r-update-a-value-in-one-column-based-on-criteria-in-other-columns)

Now look at my data:

```
class(df[1,1])
[1] "character"

>df[1,1]  

[1] "2015-03-01T00:00:00Z"

>as.Date(df[1,1])

[1] "2015-03-01"
```

So I know I can transform my data to what I want it to look like. However:

```
> df$a[df$b=="start"] <- as.Date(df$a[df$b=="start"])
> df[1,1]
[1] "16495"
```

I can change them all to a number of string, but when I try and do `as.Date` on each value it for some reason returns a strange number

I quickly tried:

```
lapply(df, function(x){if(df$b=="experience.start"){df$a<-as.Date(df$a)}})
```

Although the correct values were being printed to the console I don't know how to use this to edit my data frame.

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17030173/why-does-hello-0-return-true/17030209#17030209 ?

Comment: It seems to me that you are trying to have different classes of data in a single column, which is impossible I think. Also regarding the "strange number", 16495 is the number of days between 1970-01-01 and 2015-03-01. That's how dates are expressed when in a numeric format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge you can't because you are trying to have a column with values belonging to `character` and `Date` class. Nay you can resolve the problem in two ways.

**First Solution**

You can create another column `newdates` in this way:

```
df$newdates <- as.Date(NA)
df$newdates[df$b == "experience.start"] <- as.Date(df$a[df$b == "experience.start"])
```

with this code you will have some row `NA` filled, because not all the rows have the `b` column equal to `experience.start`.

**Second Solution**

You can agree to a compromise and convert the `Date` in `character`:

```
df$a[df$b == "experience.start"] <- as.character(as.Date(df$a[df$b=="experience.start"]))
```

in this way, the type of the `a` column will be `character` and when `b` is equal to `experience.start` you'll find a date in this format: `2015-03-04` otherwise the format will be `2011-02-11T00:00:00Z`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand your data frame set up, rather than assigning the value to the "a" variable, make a new `Date` variable and assign to that.

As Haboryme says, your existing column "a" is a character vector, and `as.Date()` returns a `Date` object, which is being converted-on-the-fly to a character -- notice the quotation marks around `"16495"`.

By assigning to a different variable, R will automatically make that a Date vector, and you also save your original information and make the code safer overall.

The code below should work and will produce the same results even if you run it several times in a row.

```
df$c <- as.Date(NA)
df$c[df$b=="start"] <- as.Date(df$a[df$b=="start"])
```

The code as you had it, even if it worked, would produce different results if run twice in a row: